# reset button for input field jquery

Tags: jquery, input, reset

I currently have a jQuery script which adds two values in a table which are price per carat and carat(weight) to give me a total price of a diamond based on it weight. Along with that i have an input field which adds a percentage to the price per carat and the price of the diamond. I have created a reset button so the user can reset their input but it does not seem to revert the values in the tables to its original values. My question is how do i make it so both the input resets and the values that it effected change as well? please see my code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function iDoMathsGood() {
        $('.amount').map(function () {
            // get all of the elements we'll need to manipulate
            var row = $(this).parent().parent();
            var originalTtl = row.find('.price');
            var adjusted = row.find('.adj_ct');

            // get the numbers we'll need and do some math        
            var cts = Number(row.find('.weight').html());
            var origPPCT = Number(row.find('.org_ct').html()) * 1000;
            var markupPrct = Number($('#markup').val()) / 100;
            var markedupCost = (origPPCT * markupPrct) + origPPCT;

            // do a little more math them set the results
            adjusted.html((markedupCost / 1000).toFixed(2));
            originalTtl.html(((origPPCT * cts) / 1000).toFixed(2));
            return $(this).html(((markedupCost * cts) / 1000).toFixed(2));
        });
    }
    iDoMathsGood();
    $('#markup').keyup(function () {
        iDoMathsGood();
    });





    //button to reset input values
    $("#btn").click(function(){
/* Single line Reset function executes on click of Reset Button */
$("#form")[0].reset();

});

});
```

/*---- update ----*/

I ending up creating a submit button with the value 0, which requires the page to load again refreshing the input. this seems to be working, if anyone has any suggestions or a more practical way to do so I would appreciate the help.

```
<form id='form'>
<input class="percent" name="markup" id="markup" value="" />
 <button id="reset"  value="submit" class="button">Reset</button> 
</form>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('input#markup').click(function() {        
        $('#reset').val('');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Does jQuery has a `reset` method? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Could you pls show your html code so I can do some test?

Comment: @iplus26 FYEO https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan !!! Okay it's night and I think I should go to bed with my dumb brain... :(

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan does .reset(); only work for form fields? Each effected row of my table has a class which i could add. I tried to add the class of that field but it wont revert to its original pricing. do you know how i would go about this?

Comment: is there a way I could revert the original values in the table along with the input field?